# Need to convert batch logon script to VBScript

Tags: vbscript

We are currently moving from using batch logon scripts to VBScript.

How should we write the following lines from our batch file in VBScript to have the equivalent effect?

```
net use p: \\server\%username%$ /persistent:yes
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: 1) Consider using Group Policy Preferences instead. 2) We're not a script writing service. What have you got so far, where exactly are you getting stuck?

Answer (score 0):

[MapNetworkDrive Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6(v=vs.84).aspx)

```
Dim WshNetwork, WshShell, username
set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
username = WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%username%")
Set WshNetwork = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Network")
WshNetwork.MapNetworkDrive "P:", "\\Server\" & username, True
```